# Multiple SLF4J binding

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/username/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.9/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.22/slf4j-simple-1.7.22.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.8/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

How can I fix this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step you should give some information about your system and much more important: what are u trying to do? As it stands you just posted a logfile. Totally unclear question.

Comment: Did you the link in "SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation."?

Answer (score 0):

Slf4j is an interface that can have several implementations. You have three implementations in your dependencies:  slf4j-log4j, slf4j-simple and logback-classic. Decide for one and exclude the other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can check solution to slf4j site, search text

> "Multiple bindings were found on the classpath"

[here](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings)

An example given at above site may not be an exact solution, you need to find which all 3rd party library uses slf4j version and exclude them while adding them as a dependency.